# MySQL GRANT is accepted but not applied

Tags: mysql, sql-grant

I am baffled.  I am creating a database on my development server, and a user for said database.  I have done this a million times, but now I am working in MySql 8.    Here is what I am attempting:

```
$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Server version: 8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 (Ubuntu)

mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'zak'@'localhost';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> flush privileges;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> exit
Bye

$ mysql -u zak -p
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Server version: 8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 (Ubuntu)

mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON wp_zakattack . * TO 'adm_zakattack'@'localhost';
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'zak'@'localhost' to database 'wp_zakattack'
mysql> show grants;
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for zak@localhost                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, RELOAD, SHUTDOWN, PROCESS, FILE, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES, SUPER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE USER, EVENT, TRIGGER, CREATE TABLESPACE, CREATE ROLE, DROP ROLE ON *.* TO `zak`@`localhost`                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 |
| GRANT APPLICATION_PASSWORD_ADMIN,AUDIT_ADMIN,AUTHENTICATION_POLICY_ADMIN,BACKUP_ADMIN,BINLOG_ADMIN,BINLOG_ENCRYPTION_ADMIN,CLONE_ADMIN,CONNECTION_ADMIN,ENCRYPTION_KEY_ADMIN,FLUSH_OPTIMIZER_COSTS,FLUSH_STATUS,FLUSH_TABLES,FLUSH_USER_RESOURCES,GROUP_REPLICATION_ADMIN,GROUP_REPLICATION_STREAM,INNODB_REDO_LOG_ARCHIVE,INNODB_REDO_LOG_ENABLE,PASSWORDLESS_USER_ADMIN,PERSIST_RO_VARIABLES_ADMIN,REPLICATION_APPLIER,REPLICATION_SLAVE_ADMIN,RESOURCE_GROUP_ADMIN,RESOURCE_GROUP_USER,ROLE_ADMIN,SERVICE_CONNECTION_ADMIN,SESSION_VARIABLES_ADMIN,SET_USER_ID,SHOW_ROUTINE,SYSTEM_USER,SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN,TABLE_ENCRYPTION_ADMIN,XA_RECOVER_ADMIN ON *.* TO `zak`@`localhost` |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I know I could just as easily do this as root .. But when this goes to production, I disable the root user, and these actions are handled by a bash script that uses the config editor for password-less login.  IE `mysql --login-path=data-main`  So I need user `'zak'@'localhost'` to be able to `GRANT` to specific users and tables.  Is there something glaring that I am missing?

Comment: You're not showing the grants that you just added. Use `SHOW GRANTS FOR adm_zakatack@localhost`

Comment: You don't need to use `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` after `GRANT`. That's only needed if you modify the internal tables instead of using commands like `GRANT`.

Comment: There are no grants for `adm_zakatack@localhost` -- I am trying to create them --> `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON wp_zakattack . * TO 'adm_zakattack'@'localhost';` While logged in as `zak@localhost` --

Comment: `There is no such grant defined for user 'adm_zakatack' on host 'localhost'` after issuing: `mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR adm_zakatack@localhost;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't give `zak` the privilege to grant privileges. That's not included in `ALL PRIVILEGES`.

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'zak'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: `WITH GRANT OPTION;` was the key.  I assumed `GRANT ALL` included the `GRANT OPTION`   Thank you.